# How do I remove the "Do you want to replace it?" dialog in Big Sur?

Tags: big-sur, preferences, apple-silicon, adobe-photoshop, dialog

On a new M1 with Big Sur I attempted to save over a file with Photoshop. Adobe has always presented a dialog box to confirm I wanted to save over a previous file. Note the "confirm" button is focused so I can quickly press return and be on my way.

[image: pshop]

But, on Big Sur a new system dialog has arrived that, again, asks me to confirm I wish to overwrite a file. Unlike the Adobe dialog this one *does not* default to confirm so I need to actually move the mouse to click on the button for this one (in addition to the old one). As a web developer I save over files hundreds of times a day so this has quickly started to annoy.

[image: big sur trying to hard]

My question is how to turn this system dialog off. I can understand being presented with the question once, but the Adobe one makes the workflow so much easier.

Comment: Just press: **⌘R**

Answer (score 2):

There is no facility in the OS to remove or disable the dialog.

Apple's dialogs have always had the safer option as the default, to avoid accidental 'click-through'. As said in the Comments, Command R will trigger the Replace command, which should be quick and easy.

Comment: Ah, of course. I recall the command+ shortcut. That is helpful but would love to just remove it.